# QR Code: choosing between error correcting vs simpler code

Tags: android, iphone, qr-code

I have a very compressed URL (10 chars). This allow me to chose between a large QR code with error correction, or a simpler QR code with less encoding.

I am trying to understand the benefit of the error correcting version. Wouldn't the simpler version be less prone to errors since the individual blocks are larger? Also, doesn't the error correction defeat its own purpose by necessitating a more complex code which could become more easily corrupted?

Which would you recommend? The QR will appear physically and could wear over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your application need a QR Code instead of a regular barcode ? Most application such as ZXING is capable to scan QR or 1D barcode.

Error correction is highly useful it the print quality is poor or if the code is exposed to external elements(thus deteriorating the code) such as on a e packaging of frozen meat or on printed advertisement enclosed behind glass. In such cases a portion of the code may be unreadable, error correction will "recover" these portion. Sometime designer will deliberate "corrupt" the code to make it aesthetically pleasing and the error correction will be used for sure.

My opinion is , if space allows add in the error correction mechanism .

Comment: Yes, in the same given space, a QR Code with a higher level of redundancy will look more elaborate. This might not be a problem if it is large enough for being read: in many cases, more cells won't be a problem. Yet I prefer a cleaner QR Code for aesthetic purposes (with a lower error correction level), it will still be redable even slightly degraded.